# Decrement or Increment decimal value

Tags: c#, decimal

in my c# solution i have :

```
private void DecrementProduct()
    {
        decimal? difference = this.Difference;

        this.Difference = new decimal?((difference.HasValue ?    difference.GetValueOrDefault() : new decimal(0))--);
    }
```

visual studio return error :
Error   107 :The operand of an increment or decrement operator must be a variable, property or indexer.

where is problem?

Comment: What are you trying to do, in plain words?

Comment: Not sure about the whole `decimal?` thing, but why are using `--` instead of `-1`? You are using `--` on an expression.

Comment: if that value is really an int or long, why are you using a decimal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void DecrementProduct()
{
    if(this.Difference.HasValue)
        this.Difference = this.Difference.Value - 1M;
    else
        this.Difference =  -1M;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is pretty self explanatory. You are using the decrement operator on a value, it needs to be a variable property or indexer.

It's akin to doing:

```
var foo = 10--;
```

You should probably just make it this:

```
this.Difference = difference - 1 ?? -1;
```

Comment: this.Difference = new decimal?(difference ?? -1);

Comment: This doesn't subtract `1` from both branches like the original attempts to do.

Comment: @Rawling It does now.